# Is the Hydrogen Electron wave-function related to a Bernoulli or binomial distribution in any way?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Is the wave-function defined below related to a bernoulli or binomial distribution in any way?

> The probability that its position $x$ will be in the interval $a \leq x \leq b$ is the integral of the density over this interval:
> $$
> P_{a \leq x \leq b}(t)=\int_{a}^{b}|\Psi(x, t)|^{2} d x
> $$
> where $t$ is the time at which the particle was measured. This leads to the normalization condition:
> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\Psi(x, t)|^{2} d x=1
> $$
> because if the particle is measured, there is $100 \%$ probability that it will be somewhere.

> The wave functions of an electron in a Hydrogen atom are expressed in terms of spherical harmonics and generalized Laguerre polynomials (these are defined differently by different authors-see main article on them and the hydrogen atom).
> It is convenient to use spherical coordinates, and the wave function can be separated into functions of each coordinate, ${ }^{[32]}$
> $$
> \Psi_{n \ell m}(r, \theta, \phi)=R(r) Y_{\ell}^{m}(\theta, \phi)
> $$

I noticed that every distribution encountered in probability textbooks is related to Bernoulli. Is this an exception?

Comment: Sorry to see this question flagged as off topic.  I think it is a legitimate question.  I also think the answer is no.  The solutions for the electron probability density function in a hydrogen atom are not related to the Bernoulli or binomial distribution in any way.  The Bernoulli and binomial distributions are discrete distributions.  They have finite, integer values.  The electron probability density is a continuous density within in a quantum state.  Certainly, there are quantum phenomenon that might be Bernoulli, e.g. is the emitted electron spin up or down.

Comment: @RCarnell It’s good that the original question was revised to make its statistical content clear. By contrast, the original post, which one can find in the edit history, has essentially no statistical content.

Comment: I’m with @Sycorax but still think this will garner better answers on [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).